# Javascript popup errors

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, chat

Having some problems with this chat system I have. It keeps giving me back these errors, which it shouldn't.

**It keeps giving me a pop-up saying "Gopher" and it's annoying**

I've looked over the code but can't find anything wrong. Anyone know anything wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var maxUsers = 50;  // maximum is 50;
    var updateResponse = "";
    var stampResponse = "";
    var resetResponse = "";
    var stampRef = "";
    var pollInterval = "";
    var nUsers = [];
    var nUserColor = ["#ff00ff","#ff6347","#1e90ff","#9932cc","#daa520","#a52a2a","#C0C0C0","#FFFF99","#CC6633","#FF9900"];

    function parseUpdateResponse(){

        var msgHistory = updateResponse;
        var tmpUsers = msgHistory.match(/\~([^\~]+)\@/g);
        if (tmpUsers != null)
            {
             tmpUsers = tmpUsers.join("").replace(/[\~\s]/g,"").split("@");
             tmpUsers.length = tmpUsers.length-1;
             nUsers = [];
             var obj = new Object();
             for (i=0; idx=tmpUsers[i]; i++)
                {
                 obj[idx] = 1;
                }
             for (idx in obj)
                {
                 nUsers.push(idx);
                }
            }
        msgHistory = msgHistory.replace(/\#/g,"<br>").split("|");
        for (i=0; i<nUsers.length; i++)
            {
             for (n=0; n<msgHistory.length; n++)
                {
                 if(msgHistory[n].match(nUsers[i]) != null)
                    {
                     msgHistory[n] = msgHistory[n].replace(/\~([^\~]+)\~/,"<strong><font color="+nUserColor[i]+">$1: <\/font><\/strong>");
                    }
                }
            }
        msgHistory = msgHistory.join(""); 
        var nChatBox = document.getElementById('msgDisp');
        nChatBox.innerHTML =  msgHistory;
        if (document.forms[0]['user'].value == "")
            {
             document.forms[0]['user'].focus();
            }
        else    {
             document.forms[0]['message'].focus();
            }
        if (nChatBox.scrollHeight > 0)
            {
             nChatBox.scrollTop = nChatBox.scrollHeight;
            }
    }

    function updateChat(){

        var updateRequest = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();   
        updateRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
             if (updateRequest.readyState == 4)
                {
                 if (updateRequest.status == 200)
                    {
                     updateResponse = updateRequest.responseText;
                     parseUpdateResponse();
                    }
                 else   {
                     alert('Error updateChat.php File '+ updateRequest.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
        var forceGET = "?n="+ parseInt(Math.random()*999999999);
        updateRequest.open("GET", "ChatFiles/updateChat.php"+forceGET, true);
        updateRequest.send(null); 
        pollInterval = setInterval("pollStamp()",7500);
    }

    function parseStampResponse(){

        var currStamp = stampResponse;
        if (currStamp != stampRef)
            {
             stampRef = currStamp;
             clearInterval(pollInterval);
             updateChat();
            }
    }

    function pollStamp(){

        var stampRequest = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();   
        stampRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
             if (stampRequest.readyState == 4)
                {
                 if (stampRequest.status == 200)
                    {
                     stampResponse = stampRequest.responseText;
                     parseStampResponse();
                    }
                 else   {
                     alert('gopher '+ stampRequest.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
        var forceGET = "?n="+ parseInt(Math.random()*999999999);
        stampRequest.open("GET", "ChatFiles/pollStamp.php"+forceGET, true);
        stampRequest.send(null); 
    }

    function sendMessage(){

        var sendRequest = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();   
        sendRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
             if (sendRequest.readyState == 4)
                {
                 if (sendRequest.status == 200)
                    {
                     pollStamp();
                    }
                 else   {
                     alert('Error newMessage.php File '+ sendRequest.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
        var forceGET = "?n="+ parseInt(Math.random()*999999999);
        var infoStr = forceGET +"&user="+document.forms[0]['user'].value;
        infoStr += "&message="+document.forms[0]['message'].value;
        document.forms[0]['message'].value = "";
        sendRequest.open("GET", "ChatFiles/newMessage.php"+infoStr, true);
        sendRequest.send(null); 
    }

    function checkSubmit(evt){

        var msgBox = document.forms[0]['message'];
        msgBox.value = msgBox.value.replace(/[\r\n\~|#@]/g,"");
        var key = (window.Event) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (key == 13)
            {
             if (msgBox.value == "" || document.forms[0]['user'].value == "")
                {
                 return false;
                }
             if (nUsers.length == 0)
                {
                 sendMessage();
                 return false;
                }
             else   {
                 for (i=0; i<nUsers.length; i++)
                    {
                     if (document.forms[0]['user'].value == nUsers[i])
                        {
                         sendMessage();
                         return false; 
                        }
                    }
                }
             if (nUsers.length < maxUsers)
                {
                 sendMessage();
                 return false;
                }
             else   {
                 alert('No more than '+maxUsers + ' Users at a time');
                }
            }
    }

    function parseResetResponse(){

        document.getElementById('pWord').value = resetResponse;
        if (resetResponse == "Okay")
            {
             nUsers.length = 0;
             document.forms[0]['user'].value = "";
             document.forms[0]['message'].value = "";
            }
    }

    function resetChat(){

        var resetRequest = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();   
        resetRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
             if (resetRequest.readyState == 4)
                {
                 if (resetRequest.status == 200)
                    {
                     resetResponse = resetRequest.responseText;
                     parseResetResponse();
                    }
                 else   {
                     alert('Error resetChat.php File '+ resetRequest.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
        var forceGET = "?n="+ parseInt(Math.random()*999999999);
        var infoStr = forceGET + "&admin="+document.getElementById('pWord').value;
        resetRequest.open("GET", "ChatFiles/resetChat.php"+infoStr, true);
        resetRequest.send(null); 
    }

    onload=updateChat;

</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id='msgDisp' class='chatBox'></div>
        <br>
        <form action="">
        <hr size=1>
        <center>Press enter on your keyboard to submit your message</center>
        <hr size=1>
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<? echo("$_SESSION[usr_name]");?>" />       
        <br />
        <textarea name='message' rows='4' cols='92' style='overflow:auto' onkeyup="checkSubmit(event)"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's good that you posted your code, but please try to narrow it down a little to the bits that you think cause the problem. E.g. *when* does it happen? After certain clicks? Find the code that corresponds to that. Also if it says 'gopher', try searching for that word in your code.

Comment: It doesn't happen all the time and it mainly happens after about 5 minutes or so. I've tried googling and seeing what the problem is, even tried moving the files into the same folder but didn't fix it. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing line 105:

```
                     alert('gopher '+ stampRequest.statusText);
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your function `pollStamp` sends an AJAX request to `ChatFiles/pollStamp.php`. This returns an error (possibly 404, page not found), which leads this bit:

```
stampRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (stampRequest.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (stampRequest.status == 200)
        {
            stampResponse = stampRequest.responseText;
            parseStampResponse();
        }
        else   {
            alert('gopher '+ stampRequest.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

to go into the "else" branch and alert 'gopher'. `pollStamp` is set to execute 7.5 seconds after the page loads by the function `updateChat`, which is the page's onload. Removing the 'alert' line (line 105) *will* stop the messages, however it doesn't fix that the request to "pollStamp.php" script isn't working.

Check if the `pollStamp.php` is in the given path: it needs to be in a folder ChatFiles which needs to be in the same folder as the script itself. If not, adjust the path here or move the file where it belongs.